# What is the expectation of P(x|z) under distribution of z parameterized by x?

Tags: probability, autoencoders, variational-bayes

This question stems from Section 2.1 of [this VAE tutorial](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05908). The problem stated in the paper is to compute the data likelihood using law of total probability:

$$
P(X) = \int P(X,z) \,\mathrm dz = \int P(X \mid z;\theta) P(z) \,\mathrm d z\,.
$$

Paragraph quoted here:

> For most $z$, $P(x \mid z)$ will be nearly zero ... This means that we need a new function $Q(z \mid X)$ which can take a value of $X$ and give us a probability over $z$ values that are likely to produce $X$ ... This lets us, for example, compute $\mathbb E_{z \sim Q} P(X \mid z)$ relatively easily.

But from the [original VAE paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114), we know that $Q(z \mid X)$ is used to approximate the posterior $P(z \mid X)$. So if the approximation is successful, then we may replace $Q(z \mid X)$ with $P(z \mid X)$ and vice versa everywhere. Therefore, the expectation in the quote becomes:

$$
\mathbb E_{z \sim Q}[P(X \mid z)] = \int P(X \mid z) Q(z \mid X) \,\mathrm d z = \int P(X \mid z) P(z \mid X) \,\mathrm d z\,.
$$

I can't even imagine what the right hand side is!

Comment: You're right, $\mathbb{E}_{q(z|x)} p(x|z)$ isn't a meaningful quantity unless $q(z|x) = p(z)$. If the author wanted to make more efficient use of samples $z$ when computing $\mathbb{E}_{p(z)} p(x|z)$ he should have used Importance Sampling: $$\mathbb{E}_{p(z)} p(x|z) = \mathbb{E}_{q(z|x)} p(x|z) \frac{p(z)}{ q(z|x)}$$